# create a plot with all dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I need to create a plot of a dataframe with several columns. I will have dates on the x-axis. How it is possible to make so that on a plot there were all dates? Now my data is shown with a period of once every five months. In some columns, the data is very small, but it is very important for me that they are visible on the plot. My dataframe looks like this.

```
    date      col1        col2      col3     col4        col5        col6
20.05.2016  1091,06     12932,31       0    9343,334    23913,74      0
27.05.2016  1086,66     11845,64       0    9786,654    23913,74      0
03.06.2016  1083,04     10762,59       0    9786,654    23913,74      0
10.06.2016  1083,96     9678,630    4000    9786,654    23913,74      0
17.06.2016  1087,31     22718,40       0    9786,654    23913,74   1412
24.06.2016  1089,78     21628,62       0    9786,654    23828,96      0
01.07.2016  1083,70     20544,92       0    9749,567    23828,96      0
08.07.2016  1081,92     19463          0    9749,567    23828,96      0
...
```

My code looks like this:

```
df.plot(figsize=(20,10), x='date', y=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'])

plt.show()
```

I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then if need subset `[]` if need filter columns by names:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']
df.set_index('date')[cols].plot(figsize=(20,10))
```

And for all columns of `df` omit it:

```
df.set_index('date').plot(figsize=(20,10))
```

But if need all columns without `0` use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and filter all columns by [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) (`!=`) and [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for all `True`s per columns:

```
#replace decimals , to . and then to floats, check notice for another solution 

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('date').replace(',', '.', regex=True).astype(float)

print (df.ne(0))
            col1  col2   col3  col4  col5   col6
date                                            
2016-05-20  True  True  False  True  True  False
2016-05-27  True  True  False  True  True  False
2016-03-06  True  True  False  True  True  False
2016-10-06  True  True   True  True  True  False
2016-06-17  True  True  False  True  True   True
2016-06-24  True  True  False  True  True  False
2016-01-07  True  True  False  True  True  False
2016-08-07  True  True  False  True  True  False

print (df.ne(0).all())
col1     True
col2     True
col3    False
col4     True
col5     True
col6    False
dtype: bool
```

---

```
df = df.loc[:, df.ne(0).all()]
print (df)
               col1      col2      col4      col5
date                                             
2016-05-20  1091.06  12932.31  9343.334  23913.74
2016-05-27  1086.66  11845.64  9786.654  23913.74
2016-03-06  1083.04  10762.59  9786.654  23913.74
2016-10-06  1083.96   9678.63  9786.654  23913.74
2016-06-17  1087.31  22718.40  9786.654  23913.74
2016-06-24  1089.78  21628.62  9786.654  23828.96
2016-01-07  1083.70  20544.92  9749.567  23828.96
2016-08-07  1081.92  19463.00  9749.567  23828.96


df.plot(figsize=(20,10))
```

**Notice**:

There is also problem with decimals, so need parameter `decimal` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) or `replace` with `astype` used in solution above:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename', index_col=['date'], decimal=',', parse_dates=['date'])

print (df)
               col1      col2  col3      col4      col5  col6
date                                                         
2016-05-20  1091.06  12932.31     0  9343.334  23913.74     0
2016-05-27  1086.66  11845.64     0  9786.654  23913.74     0
2016-03-06  1083.04  10762.59     0  9786.654  23913.74     0
2016-10-06  1083.96   9678.63  4000  9786.654  23913.74     0
2016-06-17  1087.31  22718.40     0  9786.654  23913.74  1412
2016-06-24  1089.78  21628.62     0  9786.654  23828.96     0
2016-01-07  1083.70  20544.92     0  9749.567  23828.96     0
2016-08-07  1081.92  19463.00     0  9749.567  23828.96     0
```